# How to deal with aggressive knurling?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, barbell

My EZ bar has excessive knurling that is quite painful for my hands. Is there a product to deal with it, other than wearing gloves? I was thinking some kind of wrap, similar to that used to wrap a tennis racquet handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Sports tape to the rescue!

My gym used to have the same problem, to the point where some people actually started bleeding. Calluses don't really go away if you work out a lot, and so the injuries inside the hand compounded between exercises like deadlifts, pullups and EZ-curls.

The staff at the gym eventually started taping the bars every day because of this. "Every day" because sweat and dust is pretty much absorbed by this type of tape (which, believe it or not, is a good thing, because people also use it to prevent blisters on their feet during long runs/walks). The tape will therefore become dark and dirty after a short while of consistent use.

**Availability**

If you're having this issue at your gym, chances are they have drawers full of this stuff, because it's very easy and cheap to get a hold of. And they should be used to people using it on certain pieces of equipment. Especially pullup bars, where people have vastly differing preferences in term of grip.

If you're having this problem at home, then go to your local sports shop. If they don't have it, they have no business calling themselves a sports shop!

Comment: The tape arrived by mail last night. I tried it out, works like a charm!

Comment: @user443854 - Great to hear!

Answer (score 3):

You could also try out "Fat Grips". You put them on the bar and have a rubbery feel to them. They can also be placed on dumb bells and regular bars.

Their purpose is to make the bar thicker to work your forearms more but they might help with your problem.

If you look on amazon you'll find them and many other brands.